# In the new version android studio(3.2), how do I get the apk file?

Tags: android-studio, apk

In the new version android studio(3.2), how do I get the apk file(I do not want .aab) for publish? I want to publish my application in a store other than Google, but only the apk file can be released. Please help. I do not know English well. I’m sorry if something I wrote wrong

Comment: In what "new version"…?

Comment: in android studio...version 3.2...

Comment: if want apk then generate and put in playstore console and publish .See this to know about app bundle https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/

Answer (score 0):

Within the "Build" menu there is a submenu "Build Bundle(s) / APK(s)". There you can just select "Build APK(s)". The resulting file will be saved in `app/build/outputs/apk`.

Alternatively you can use the "Generated signed Bundle/APK" wizard which can found be found in the "Build" menu as well. Just select the lower option ("APK").

Comment: But written to publish the program Option android app bundle to be selected...
and lower option for test app?

Comment: You can still upload regular apks to Google Play. Bundles have the benefit of a much smaller download size since only the resources relevant to the specific device need to be downloaded. However, you have to upload your keystore to Google Play. If you want to publish to other stores like FDroid or Amazon or send your app directly for testing, you still need to use regular APKs.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload anything to Google playstore either bundle or apk 
see this to know more about [bundle](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/)

click on build ,

then on generate signed bunde/ apk 
when the popup appear select apk(at bootom) 
click next 
choose key store path or create new 
click next 
On signature version checked both the option 
click finish 

on event log you will see message of creation and path where it has created